# Why won't my $.ajax call return a json object from a cshtml file?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have this jquery that uses ajax in an attempt to return a json object, but I am no pro at ajax, though I have used it before with json, only I was loading a json file and not trying to return a string from a cshtml page that queries a database for information (as I am doing here).

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/AJAX Pages/Compute_Calendar_Events.cshtml",
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (jsonObj) {
        console.log("AJAX SUCCESS!");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        alert("NO AJAX!");
    }
});
```

(Also I have tried "application/json; charset=UTF-8" as the contentType, but it changes no behavior).

**Here is the cshtml page that I point AJAX to:**

```
@{
    Layout = "";

    if(IsAjax || 1==1)
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"events\":[";
        string selectQueryString = "SELECT title, summary, eventDate FROM CalendarEvents ORDER BY eventDate ASC";
        var db = Database.Open("Content");
        foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
        {
            jsonString += "{";
            jsonString += "\"title\":" + Json.Encode(row.title) + ",";
            jsonString += "\"dateNumber\":" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(0, row.eventDate.ToString().IndexOf("/"))) + ",";
            jsonString += "\"dateMonth\":" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(row.eventDate.ToString().IndexOf("/") + 1, row.eventDate.ToString().LastIndexOf("/") - (row.eventDate.ToString().IndexOf("/") + 1))) + ",";
            jsonString += "\"dateYear\":" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(row.eventDate.ToString().LastIndexOf("/") + 1, 4)) + ",";
            jsonString += "\"summary\":" + Json.Encode(row.summary);
            jsonString += "},";
        }
        jsonString = jsonString.TrimEnd(',');
        jsonString += "]}";
        /*System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/TEST.txt"));
        var outputFile = System.IO.File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("~/TEST.txt"));
        outputFile.Write(jsonString);
        outputFile.Close();*/
@*      *@@jsonString
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

**It is very important to note a couple of things:**

1. I get no server-side error or error code.
2. I have written the output to a simple .txt file to test the contents, and by pasting it into jsonLint (found here: http://jsonlint.com/) I was easily able to determine that this is, indeed, valid json syntax.
3. I am still always getting the alert message that runs only under the "error: function()" option of the $.ajax call.
4. I am getting no white space either before or after the entire jsonString (not that that probably matters).
5. I am in a WebMatrix, C#, asp.net-webpages environment.
6. My only two suspicions are **1)** The dataType and/or contentType is not set correctly, or **2)** The last time I had to use ajax for json (targeting an actual .json file) I had to change a setting in "IIS Express" to allow it to receive data from json files, however, I thought that this was only needed if actually using ajax to parse a json "file" and not just json data. Also, no matter where I look, I can't seem to find this resource anymore.
7. The textStatus and error parameter values are: **textStatus: parsererror error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token &** but this doesn't seem to throw any red flags in my mind, because I know that the json syntax by itself checks out okay.

**Thanks to everyone for all of your help. I believe I have found the issue (the unexpected ampersand token finally made a light bulb go on in my head). I have added the answer to this page, in the event that it may help someone else in the future.**

Comment: The error indicates that there was an error on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: And `contentType` is irrelevant with `type: "GET"`, because there's no content (`contentType` refers to the form values, `dataType` refers to the response).

Comment: You should use Json.Write to generate the JSON,. You shouldn't construct it like that yourself: `Json.Write(db.Query(selectQueryString), Response.Output)`

Comment: @MikeBrind I'll give it a shot, but I hate to mess with code that's working...lol. Anyway, I take it that `Json.Write` writes directly to the page? How can I preserve the same name/value pairs like what I constructed myself?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for telling me that. Yeah, I didn't know what contentType was, really. I'm not even 100% clear on everything dataType does.

Comment: `dataType` tells jQuery how it should parse the response from the server. If you specify `json`, it automatically calls `jQuery.parseJSON()`; if you specify `xml` it calls `jQuery.parseXML()`.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, that's pretty much what I was thinking, but never verified it. Thanks for confirming that! How would you explain contentType? Is it how the name/value pairs sent in the "data" option is formatted when given to the server on POST?

Comment: @VoidKing You can use aliases in your SQL to generate the JSON properties: `SELECT datepart (dw, [eventDate) as dateNumber,` --etc.

Comment: @MikeBrind Okay, thank you for that! I assume it writes directly to the page, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the problem came as a result of razor's automatic HTML encoding (thus turning many characters into their `&...;` HTML encoded equivalents).

Thus instead of writing `@jsonString` I needed to be writing `@Html.Raw(jsonString)` thus bypassing (as I intended originally) any further encoding that could warp the json syntax.

Also, I didn't find it necessary to add the `Response.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json");` line, even though I am using `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON`

Again, thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Just on a side note, you can build the entire string in Razor instead of with string concatenation. You're already inside a templating engine, might as well use it :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have no idea what you are talking about, LOL I would love an example!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Actually, maybe I should say, I have no idea how I would benefit from this alternative.

Comment: http://tipranks.com/javascripts/articles.cshtml is being driven by http://paste.ubuntu.com/5684036/ , look at how simple the code is, when I edit the JSON, I get correct syntax indication and don't have to deal with escaping and stuff. Worth mentioning, this has nothing to do with user-input, it's all our input. Also, sanitizing is done on the client side with Mustache.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue,

I've solved it by heading a header in the top of the `.cshtml` file in WebMatrix

```
@{
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
}
```

Another thing to check is that your JSON passes validation. Copy-Paste your JSON result in a JSON validator and make sure it passes. (You already did that, I'd like future readers of this question to see this).

Here is sample code you can grab your JSON with

```
$.getJSON("/AJAX Pages/Compute_Calendar_Events.cshtml").done(function(result){
    alert("Success!");
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(){
    alert("Error loading");
});
```

Comment: As I stated, I used JSONLint to ensure that the json syntax was valid, and it is.

Comment: I am trying your answer now.

Comment: `$.getJSON` automatically assumes JSON content type, it doesn't care about the header.

Comment: @Barmar right, I suspect that ASP.NET might add additional code because of the unspecified ContentType (assuming text/html). I don't really suspect the client side. Good comment though.

Comment: +1 for using `.done` and showing me how to get the equivalent of `async: false` with `$.getJSON` (if, indeed, I am getting that right). Sometimes I overlook simple methods that combine well!